# How to use FragmentTransaction in code?

Tags: android, replace, fragment

I want to change the fragment in my container with this code:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_app_launch, container, false);

        SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("meetme_first_start", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int firstStart = getSharedPreferences.getInt("first_start", 0);
        if (firstStart == 0) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = new FragmentTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, new TargetFragment());

        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

But it says it `cannot instantiate the type FragmentTransaction`. Anyone knows help?

Answer (score 2):

The right way to get an instance of `FragmentTransaction` is in this way:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

Or a one-liner:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this,

```
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.container, new TargetFragment()).commit();
```